# Zimbra + Fetchmail

Tags: zimbra

I’m migrating from an old Merak mail server to Zimbra. I has to be done without any downtime.
My idea was to:

1) Make zimbra work as a relay for the current server (zimbra can send mail through the ode server)

2) Set a POP3 connector like Fetchmail to download incoming mail from the old server (this way mail stays on the old and the new server)

3) After all users are migrated to the new server change the MX record to point to the new one and disable the relay function.

My question is about Fetchmail. Has anyone any experience wit it? Are there any known problems with Fetchmail and Zimbra?

Maybe someone has a good tutorial on how to integrate it with Zimbra?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have IMAP enabled for the old Merak server? The simplest solution would probably to do a user by user imapsync (https://imapsync.lamiral.info/) to get the mailboxes in Merak in sync with the ones on Zimbra.

Because Imapsync will be able to review and copy over only changes since the last sync, you would be able to run through a few passes of imapsync until you get the delta very small (thus quick sync runs).

At which point when the runs are short and an imapsync run just takes a few minutes to step through the accounts you would cut over MX and tell your users the new system is live.

You could then do a cleanup imapsync to make sure you copied everything over. With the Zimbra external email settings, you could even have the users setup to see their old Merak mailbox (clearly marked as OLD or LEGACY) there for them to see the old mail and just as a final check that everything was copied over.